# I have a problem with 2D arrays in RUBY where it doesn't assign the values into it

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
PLAYERS = 4

def input(noteam, arraya)
  for x in 0..noteam-1
    for y in 0..PLAYERS-1
      arraya[x] = Array.new(PLAYERS)
        puts "Team " + (x+1).to_s
        arraya[x][y] = read_integer("Enter score for individual player " + (y+1).to_s)
    end
  end
end

def disp_arr(myarray, row, col)
  print myarray[0]
  for x in 0..row-1
    for y in 0..col-1
      print myarray[x][y]
    end
  end
end

def main
  notm = read_integer("How many teams:")

  arraya = Array.new(notm)

  input(notm, arraya)

  disp_arr(arraya, notm, PLAYERS)
end

main                        #=> invoking the main method
```

So I tried doing print myarray[0] for the first row and [nil,nil,nil,10] comes out so I know that there's a problem with assigning the value into the array but I'm not too sure whats wrong with it.

Comment: Using `for` loops is very unidiomatic in Ruby. Try to rewrite your code using [`times`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Integer.html#method-i-times) and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map). You can even pass a block to [`Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-c-new) to populate the array. In `disp_arr` you should use [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-each) to traverse the array. And there's no need to pass the array's size – an array knows its [`size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move line `arraya[x] = Array.new(PLAYERS)` out of internal `for` loop

```
def input(noteam, arraya)
  for x in 0..noteam-1
    arraya[x] = Array.new(PLAYERS) # <- 
    puts "Team #{x + 1}"
    for y in 0..PLAYERS-1
      puts "Player: #{y + 1}"
      arraya[x][y] = read_integer("Enter score for individual player " + (y+1).to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

Your original code reset `arraya[x]` to new array for every team player except last.
That is why you observing `[nil, nil, nil, 45]` result, because only last player results being saved.